# Calculating Daily average for same date using mutate(across) in R

Tags: r

I am trying a code that used to word in a different set, to calculate average of rows, if two rows persist per the same date. However, I encounter some problems, The code doesn't omit lines.
Some dates have multiple temperatures, but most days only have one..
I tried manipulating the Date object, with no luck.
This is really a copy paste of a previous well run code.

Here is an example -

```
w_avg <- df %>% group_by(DATE) %>% 
  mutate(across(c("TMIN","TMAX"), ~mean(.x, na.rm=T)))

 ##data example below-
structure(list(STATION = c("USW00024233", "USW00024233", "USW00024233", 
"USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", 
"USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", 
"USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", 
"USW00024233", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", 
"USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", 
"USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", 
"USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USW00024233", "USW00024233", "USW00024233", 
"USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", 
"USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", 
"USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", 
"USW00024233", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", 
"USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", 
"USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", 
"USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", 
"USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USW00024233", "USW00024233", "USW00024233", 
"USW00024233", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", 
"USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", 
"USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", 
"USC00458773", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", "USC00458773", "USW00024233", 
"USC00458773", "USW00024233"), NAME = c("SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", 
"SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US", "VANCOUVER 4 NNE, WA US", "SEATTLE TACOMA AIRPORT, WA US"
), DATE = structure(c(16788, 16503, 14913, 15230, 17276, 15021, 
18021, 15781, 16502, 16763, 15070, 14978, 16837, 17756, 16275, 
18272, 14909, 16268, 17079, 16670, 16756, 18110, 15322, 16811, 
17497, 17740, 15662, 17999, 17721, 14857, 16529, 16650, 17605, 
17905, 16072, 16163, 15874, 17264, 16640, 16923, 15611, 16363, 
17215, 18017, 17083, 16362, 18237, 16550, 15547, 15330, 16409, 
14828, 17399, 15448, 15123, 16338, 16275, 15217, 16704, 18177, 
18065, 15611, 15514, 15754, 18149, 18086, 15440, 16868, 16183, 
16514, 16115, 14917, 17603, 15123, 16342, 16197, 14847, 16522, 
17036, 17122, 18048, 16015, 18379, 16977, 17654, 17096, 17005, 
18002, 17480, 15810, 15361, 16406, 16330, 15646, 15040, 15930, 
17041, 16673, 18251, 15162), class = "Date"), TMAX = c(8.3, 14.4, 
13.3, 17.8, 12.8, 7.2, 21.7, 7.8, 18.9, 6.7, 11.7, 3.9, 8.9, 
23.3, 20.6, 7.2, 10, 30.6, 18.3, 27.8, 10.6, 30, 4.4, 10, 12.8, 
30.6, 12.2, 14.4, 28.3, 21.1, 8.9, 25, 11.1, 7.8, 10.6, 13.3, 
23.3, 11.1, 25, 30.6, 25, 22.2, 13.3, 19.4, 18.9, 22.2, 8.3, 
13.3, 25.6, 5.6, 5, 25.6, 25, 13.3, 15, 17.8, 18.9, 20.6, 18.9, 
18.3, 25, 27.2, 18.3, 7.8, 18.9, 23.3, 18.3, 11.7, 11.7, 17.2, 
11.7, 21.7, 19.4, 16.7, 16.7, 18.3, 20.6, 15.6, 26.7, 10.6, 25.6, 
12.8, 18.9, 22.2, 22.2, 15.6, 22.8, 10.6, 11.1, 12.8, 6.7, 5.6, 
21.7, 15, 9.4, 27.8, 26.1, 28.3, 12.2, 19.4), TMIN = c(2.8, 4.4, 
8.3, 13.9, 5.6, 0, 5.6, -0.6, -1.7, 2.8, 4.4, NA, 3.9, 12.2, 
12.8, 3.9, 1.7, 12.8, 11.1, 13.9, 2.2, 13.9, 0.6, -3.3, 3.3, 
12.8, 1.1, 5, 12.2, 10.6, 2.2, 14.4, -1.7, 3.3, 6.1, 6.1, 13.3, 
5, 10.6, 12.2, 12.2, 12.8, 5, -0.6, 12.2, 12.8, -1.1, 5.6, 12.8, 
-5.6, 1.7, 12.2, 12.8, 7.2, 10, 12.8, 13.3, 11.1, 2.2, 3.9, 12.8, 
10.6, 11.1, 3.9, 12.2, 11.7, 5, 3.9, 6.1, 2.8, 6.1, 3.3, 2.8, 
7.2, 11.1, 7.2, 12.8, 9.4, 12.2, 5, 10, 7.8, 3.3, 13.3, 5, 8.9, 
14.4, 1.1, 3.9, 0.6, 2.2, -3.2, 11.1, 8.3, -2.8, 15, 9.4, 13.9, 
8.9, 12.2)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
library(dplyr)
w_avg <- df %>% group_by(DATE) %>% select(4:5) %>%
  summarise_all(mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you tell me why you had to omit some of the colums?

Comment: @Stat.Enthus Otherwise, funtions of style `_all` use all variables. If I do not omit some variables from `df` then `mean()` would be computed for all of them. I hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since you're only summarizing 2 columns, you can specify them directly in `summarise()` as follows.

```
w_avg <- df %>% group_by(DATE) %>%
     summarise(avg_tmin = mean(TMIN,na.rm=TRUE),
               avg_tmax = mean(TMAX,na.rm=TRUE))
head(w_avg)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(w_avg)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  DATE       avg_tmin avg_tmax
  <date>        <dbl>    <dbl>
1 2010-08-07     12.2     25.6
2 2010-08-26     12.8     20.6
3 2010-09-05     10.6     21.1
4 2010-10-27      1.7     10  
5 2010-10-31      8.3     13.3
6 2010-11-04      3.3     21.7
```

If you're using R 4.0 and `dplyr 1.0.0`, you can use `across()` within `summarise()`:

```
w_avg <- df %>% group_by(DATE) %>%
     summarise(across(c(TMIN,TMAX),~mean(.x,na.rm=TRUE)))
head(w_avg)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(w_avg)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  DATE        TMIN  TMAX
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl>
1 2010-08-07  12.2  25.6
2 2010-08-26  12.8  20.6
3 2010-09-05  10.6  21.1
4 2010-10-27   1.7  10  
5 2010-10-31   8.3  13.3
6 2010-11-04   3.3  21.7
```

Comment: Thanks. This was my code in R4.0 and dplyr 1.0.0, and didn't work. I was curious why

Comment: @Stat.Enthus - hmm... what error message(s) did you receive?